# New UI feature question

Tags: discussion

In the new UI for EE.SE, I noticed a feature on my profile page which I can't figure out.

[image]

What does the "85/100 score" and "28/20 answers" mean (outlined in red)?.   There is no rollover explanation (which would have been nice).  If I missed the explanation for this somewhere else, I apologize.

Answer (score 6):

This shows progress towards the tag badge.  The tag barge in this case is bronze for USB.  You need a score of 100 for that tag, and you already have 85.  You need to answer 20 questions, and you have answered 28.

Comment: Is this explained somewhere (besides your answer)?

Comment: It might be explained in the badge description.

Comment: @tcrosley The badge requirement is explained [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) (for bronze, at least).

Comment: @Null Thanks, but that page doesn't explain the numbers on the profile page inside the red box I displayed in my question, i.e. 85/100 score and 28/20 answers.

Comment: @tcrosley don't know where it's documented but on SE score is the nett votes on your 28 answers. So for example your score of 85 might mean you've gone 86 upvotes on answers for that tag and one downvote. You need to get to 100 for the tag badge.

Comment: @PeterJ That's explained in the answer above.  I was just wondering where on the site someone could find this information -- I sure couldn't.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Answer (score 1):

As @NickAlexeev says, this is your progress towards your closest Tag Badge.

In my case there is an extra icon to the right of the graph. This icon does have a rollover explanation:

[image: rep]

I assume you don't have that option because you've achieved all the privileges! Well done!  Without this rollover there's nothing to say what's going on.