# I give up, what do the score stats mean?

Tags: support, user-accounts

OK so once you get to a certain rep you get to see these numbers.

Help is useless.

Anyone know what they mean?

[image]

Comment: It's a measure of your overall worth as a human being.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ha-ha.. way too high a score for that ;D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New UI feature question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/new-ui-feature-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how much score (upvotes) remain and how many questions you need to answer until you get that tag badge (bronze badge for [circuit-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-analysis) in your case).

[image]

You have 97 upvotes out of 100 required.
You have answered 32 questions, while 20 is required.

Comment: OIC.... thanks bud.

Comment: @Trevor_G The "help" page for the tag badges is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags

Comment: @W5VO yes I just did not put the two together, I did not realize they were connected being shown so far apart like that. But when I click on the little gear I see them listed individually per "badge" so now I get it.